# Is it possible to export binaries from a non Hyper-V machine to a Hyper-V enabled one to test an app?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-emulator

I am currently running a VM that has VS 2012 installed with Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 but cannot enable Hyper-V in the VM. I want to test my Windows phone app using the Emulator.

Is it possible to export the binaries to another machine that has VS 2012 and Hyper-V enabled to test the app?

Comment: Do you happen to be using TFS or VSO?

Comment: @AndrewClear Yes, we use TFS. Would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to copy the VHD attached to the VM on to the machine that has Hyper-V enabled, mount the VHD there and open/run the solution from the mounted volume.

PS: If the VHD is on a shared storage, you do not need to copy the VHD, just turn off the VM and mount the disk from network.

Comment: Also, why not just copy the Visual Studio solution in a shared storage or version control so that you can access from both VM and Hyper-V machine? If that is not an option, you can just copy the VS solution folder every time you want to test.

Comment: So you are saying that I can build the solution on a different machine with Hyper-V as long as I have TFS setup on both?

Comment: @stackErr I mean, if you have your project in TFS or GITHub, you can sync the code to both the machines... You can continue to develop your code on the VM and then sync it to the test machine to run.